# How can I goose bean shell into operating as a math parser?

Tags: java, beanshell

I am using a Bean Shell interpreter in a for loop like this

```
    for(int i = 0; i <functionSize; i++){
         interpreter.set("x", i);
         yvalues[i] = (Integer) interpreter.eval(functionString);
    }
```

The problem I am having is that when I do the function 2^x I get really strange output. The list of the first few y values is like this: 2, 3, 0 , 1, 6, 7, 4, 5, 10 , 11, 8 , 9 ...

Does anybody know how to get the bean shell interpreter to correctly evaluate powers?

Edit: I would like to use the bean shell interpreter in place of writing a math parser. Does anyone know how I can get the bean shell to evaluate powers of functions of x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `2^x` represents bitwise XOR, not exponentiation. Use [`Math.pow(2,x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) if you like, but realize that it operates on doubles, not ints, so will give you a floating-point answer that will probably cause an exception when you try to cast the result as an integer.

edit: there is also [BigInteger.pow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29), which returns a BigInteger.

Or, if you want powers of 2, but not any other base, use the expression for left shift: `1 << x` for x between 0 and 31.

Comment: Is there not a way to get bean shell to evaluate powers? That would be the most convenient and would keep the code simpler. I wouldn't have to have a separate case for parsing powers.

Comment: Um, BeanShell is Java. Java is what it is. If you want to provide a function (some class with a method) yourself and assign it to a variable you expose to BeanShell, that's up to you.

Comment: But there's no *operator* representing exponentiation in Java.

Comment: It was my understanding that bean shell interpreter could parse math expressions and evaluate them. I used it to avoid writing my own parser. So you are saying that I should just write my own parser?

Comment: BeanShell is basically an interpreter for Java. Maybe you should look at using Jython instead: Python has the ** operator for exponentiation, along with builtin bignum support. Of course, with any interpreter, you have to watch out for security issues. If you *only* want mathematical expressions evaluated, and not arbitrary code, yes, you should probably write your own parser, otherwise you expose yourself to security issues.

Comment: Or use some other off-the-shelf Java solution for math expression evaluation. There's apparently one out there in JEP (http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) but I've never used it.

Comment: Yeah, you have to pay for JEP, kindof shocking that there isn't just some quick java solution that will parse math... seems pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up editing to:

```
 double y = Double.parseDouble(interpreter.eval(functionString).toString());
 yvalues[i] = (int) y;
```

And using `Math.pow(a, b)` as my input.

Doesn't look pretty, but its working.